# Inner product of signatures of piecewise linear paths

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, rough-path-theory

It is a well-know observation that, given two points $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^d$, the path signature associated to their linear interpolation is given by the tensor exponential. Precisely, if $\Delta x$ denotes the linear interpolation $x_1 \rightarrow x_2$, then
$$S(\Delta x) = \left(1 , \Delta x, \frac{\Delta x^{\otimes 2}}{2!}, \frac{\Delta x^{\otimes 3}}{3!}, ... \right) =: \exp_\otimes(\Delta x) \in T((\mathbb{R}^d)),$$
where $S(\cdot)$ denotes the signature map and $T((\mathbb{R}^d))$ is the extended tensor algebra. Actually, the signature takes value in a subset $T^1$ of $T((\mathbb{R}^d))$ which can be endowed with an inner product, and thus becomes a Hilbert space if one takes the appropriate completions. I refer to [this work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.10971.pdf) for a proper definition, but I assume most readers interested in this post are familiar with this.

Now, instead of considering just a line segment, let us consider a piecewise linear path. Specifically, given a finite number of points $x_1,...,x_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, we consider the path corresponding to successive linear interpolations, i.e. $x_1 \rightarrow x_2$ concatenated with $x_2 \rightarrow x_3$, which, in its turn, we concatenate with $x_3 \rightarrow x_4$, and so on. Let us denote this piecewise linear path by $\textbf{x}$.

Thanks to Chen's identity, we know that the signature of $\textbf{x}$ is given by multiplying in the extended tensor algebra the signatures associated to each interpolation, i.e.
$$S(\textbf{x}) = \exp_\otimes(\Delta_1 x) \ \otimes \ \exp_\otimes(\Delta_2 x) \ \otimes \ ... \ \otimes \exp_\otimes(\Delta_{n-1} x),$$
where $\Delta_i x$ denotes the interpolated path $x_i \rightarrow x_{i+1}$, and $\otimes$ is the [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra#Non-commutative_polynomials) defined in $T((\mathbb{R}^d))$.

Lastly, let $\textbf{y}$ denote some other piecewise linear interpolation of $y_1,...,y_n\in \mathbb{R}^d$, and let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{T^1}$ denote the aforementioned inner product. My question is:

> Can we express $\langle S(\textbf{x}), S(\textbf{y}) \rangle_{T^1}$ via the simpler inner products $\langle \exp_\otimes(\Delta_i x), \exp_\otimes(\Delta_j y) \rangle_{T^1}$ with $i,j \in \{1,...,n-1\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to define an inner product in $T^1(V)$. As far as I am aware this is defined by summing all of the component-wise inner products for each tensor power; but, this is only guaranteed to converge in the range of the signature thanks to the factorial decay. Ilya's work that you link doesn't define the inner product at all (ctrl+F for "inner, dot, scalar" yielded nothing). I will assume this definition I have just mentioned since we are working with signatures.

To get a positive answer to your question, something that would help is if the algebra product $\otimes$ interacts well with the scalar product, in the sense $<a\otimes b, c\otimes d> = <a, c> <b, d>$

Unfortunately, this doesn't even work at the first level.

$<a\otimes b, c\otimes d> = <(1,a^1+b^1, ...), (1,c^1+d^1, ...)>$
$<(1,\sum_{i=0}^d a_i^1+b_i^1, ...), (1,\sum_{i=0}^d c_i^1+d_i^1, ...)>$
$=<(1,\sum_{i=0}^d a_i^1+b_i^1, ...), (1,\sum_{i=0}^d c_i^1+d_i^1, ...)>$
$=1+\sum_{i=0}^d (a_i^1+b_i^1)(c_i^1+d_i^1)+...$

whereas

$<a,c> <b , d> = (1+\sum_{i=0}^d a_i^1 c_i^1 +...)(1+\sum_{i=0}^d  b_i^1  d_i^1 +...)$

so there's no way of "retrieving" the term $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i^1 d_i^1$ from the LHS in the RHS. This is just illustrative.

Now, to answer your question succinctly: in fact, you cannot retrieve $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i^1 d_i^1$ at all from $<a, c>$ and $<b, d>$ (can you see why?). As a result: no, you cannot retrieve the whole inner product of the algebra product $\otimes$ of the pieces (of your path) *only from* the the inner products of the pieces.

Comment: Hey @Martin Geller, thanks for your reply. Indeed the link was referring to the wrong work. Apologies. I've now put the correct work by Ilya. That "good interaction" that you refer to is clearly not satisfied, I agree. That doesn't mean, however, that it's impossible to represent $\langle S(\textbf{x}), S(\textbf{y}) \rangle_{T^1}$ as a function of $\langle \exp_\otimes(\Delta_i x), \exp_\otimes(\Delta_i y) \rangle_{T^1}$.

Comment: That's exactly why I said that my calculations were merely illustrative. I answered your question in the last paragraph, and I've asked if you could see why we can't retrieve $$\sum_{i=0}^d a_i^1 d_i^1$$ from the information in $<a\otimes c>$ and $<b\otimes d>$. The key insight is that $<a\otimes c>$ only contains $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i^1 c_i^1$ and $<b\otimes d>$ only contains $\sum_{i=0}^d b_i^1 d_i^1$. Without knowing "($a_i$ or $c_i$) and ($b_i$ or $d_i$)" , you cannot get to $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i^1 d_i^1$, from $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i^1 c_i^1$ and  $\sum_{i=0}^d b_i^1 d_i^1$.

Comment: And, without $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i^1 d_i^1$, you cannot compute $\sum_{i=0}^d (a_i^1+b_i^1)(c_i^1+d_i^1)$, and hence you cannot compute even the first level of $<a\otimes b, c\otimes d>$.

Comment: I understand, but besides $\langle a, c \rangle$ and $\langle b,d \rangle$ you can also consider $\langle a, d \rangle$, $\langle a, b \rangle$, and all the other combinations. Here, I'm using the commonly used notation instead of your $\langle a \otimes c \rangle$.

Comment: That’s not quite what you asked in your question. Notice how you write $\langle \exp_\otimes(\Delta_i x), \exp_\otimes(\Delta_i y) \rangle_{T^1}$  for all $i$, instead of $\langle \exp_\otimes(\Delta_i x), \exp_\otimes(\Delta_j y) \rangle_{T^1}$ for all $i,j$. So you’re not allowed to consider the “cross-terms” you’re describing. Forgive my typo regarding the use of $<a\otimes b>$ instead of $<a,b>$, I’ve just fixed it

Comment: That's a nice observation! Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question. Also, +1, though I won't mark the post as answered just yet.

Comment: To answer your new question, work out at level 2 what the expression for $<a\otimes b, c\otimes d> $ is. Remember that you only care about the first two levels of $$a\otimes b= (1, \sum_i a^1_i+b^1_i, \sum_{ij} a^2_{ij}+b^2_{ij}  + a_i \otimes b_j, …). $$ Once you have expanded out $<a\otimes b, c\otimes d> $ and can recognise several different terms, then expand $<a,b>,<a,c>, …$ (probably just expand the first one and then replace $b$’s for $c$’s and so forth, and you don’t really need to write out each one). Then try and see if you can recover the terms in $<a\otimes b, c\otimes d> $ from…

Comment: …the terms in $<a,b>,<a,c>, …$, etc. Let me know how you get on.